# how to find where the user tapped on the screen in ios

Tags: ios, xcode4, mapkit

I want to find where user tapped on MapKit. I cannot find a action to make a connection so i am wondering there is an alternate method for the same. please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Disco S2 says, add the instance of MKMapView as a subview to your view. To know where your user tapped on the map, use this method:

```
- (CGPoint)convertCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate toPointToView:(UIView *)view
```

Comment: After I get a sub view(map kit) to the parent view ... still  getting a white screen..

Comment: After adding mapview to view, you are getting a white screen or is it happening after you tap on your map

Answer (score 0):

Put the mapkit inside a view and listen for touches in that view. There is then a method to convert the touch in the mapView to a touch in the view and vice versa. I can't remember the method for converting but it will be in the map kit documentation