# how to read longitude and latitude when user taps on google map ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, xcode4, mapkit

I am trying to read the location  where user tapped on google map(map kit) and then drop a pin at that point. I have tried to read the taps location in blank view and it is done successfully but when I did the same with google map,nothing happen...PLease help..

Comment: Get the touch event, see if the coordinates are inside the map view, and then convert pixels to lat, long with mkmapview's convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:. Then just add an annotation there.

Comment: See the answer to [How to capture Tap gesture on MKMapView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317810/how-to-capture-tap-gesture-on-mkmapview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531683/how-to-find-where-the-user-tapped-on-the-screen-in-ios/6532850#6532850) you know where the user tapped. As @Jano suggests, you can add annotation after you get the coordinates